# move the horizontal line up and down

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have a thermometer of svg type. I want to create some animation using Snap. I could animate the text with the given value but could not animate the dashed line that you can see in the screenshot to move as per the given value. How should i do it?

[image]

Here is my code

```
const svg = Snap(this.svg);
    const { color } = this.state;
    svg.line(55, 366, 90, 366).attr({
      id: 'marker-line',
      stroke: color,
      strokeDasharray: '2 4',
      strokeWidth: '1'
});



 const animateMarker = (value, svg, marker, lastValue) => {
      // Snap.animate(value);
      const markerLine = svg.select('#marker-line');
      if (markerLine) {
        Snap.animate(
          lastValue || 0,
          value,
          val => {
            // markerLine.attr({ y1: 366-val });
            marker.textContent = roundOffDecimalDigit(val, 2); // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
          },
          400
        );
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code, it's difficult to tell. Your code looks ok though, just it only sets one of the y co-ordinates, and I assume you want to set both. Eg

```
Snap.animate(lastValue,value, function( val ) { markerLine.attr({ y1: val, y2: val }); }, 400 )
```

If it's still not working, try putting it on a jsfiddle and it will be easier to help.